# Работа с DOM в Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Я могу взаимодействовать с DOM различными способами (getElementById, getElementsByClassName, querySelector и так далее) но в моем проекте установлена библиотека SweetAlert2 и часть классов в которые нужно внести изменения генерирует Javascript, и вот именно с этими элементами я не могу взаимодействовать, т.к мне возвращается null. Мой код инклюдится в самом низу страницы перед закрывающимся тегом body, это значит что на момент отработки моих методов DOM дерево должно быть полностью загружено. В чем заключается проблема? Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что элементы, которые Вы пытаетесь найти, создаются позднее, в ответ на действия пользователя.